# Permission denied activating virtualenv with apache + mod_wsgi + django in Centos 7

Tags: django, apache, centos, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I don't even know how much I tried to deploy a django app with `apache` and `mod_wsgi` but still gets the same error again and again, this is `wsgi.py` file:

```
"""
WSGI config for progress_bar project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named  ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/tone/entornos/progressbar/lib/python2.7/site-packages')


sys.path.append('/var/www/html/progress_bar/progress_bar')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/progress_bar')


# Add virtualenv and activate for apache
    activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/tone/entornos/progressbar/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "progress_bar.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And `virtual-host` config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #WSGIDaemonProcess python-path=/home/tone/entornos/progressbar/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   #WSGIPythonPath /home/tone/entornos/progressbar/bin:/home/tone/entornos/progressbar/lib/python2.7/site-packages

   WSGIScriptAlias /progress-django-upload /var/www/html/progress_bar/progress_bar/wsgi.py

   <Directory /var/www/html/progress_bar>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But always I tried to acces I have a nice error 500 and log says the same:

```
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.427639 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376] mod_wsgi (pid=4217): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/progress_ba$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.427799 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376] mod_wsgi (pid=4217): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/v$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.427894 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.427981 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376]   File "/var/www/html/progress_bar/progress_bar/wsgi.py", line 24,$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.428421 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:12.428567 2015] [:error] [pid 4217] [client 150.214.108.153:50376] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/tone/entornos/progre$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.450602 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377] mod_wsgi (pid=4216): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/progress_ba$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.450722 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377] mod_wsgi (pid=4216): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/v$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.450811 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.450889 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377]   File "/var/www/html/progress_bar/progress_bar/wsgi.py", line 24,$
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.451162 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
    [Fri Mar 13 13:19:14.451249 2015] [:error] [pid 4216] [client 150.214.108.153:50377] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/tone/entornos/progre$
```

Before you answer... yes, I set permission for apache with `chown -R apache:apache /home/tone/entornos/progressbar/bin` even to `activate_this.py` to `chomd 777 ...` and even disable SELinux temporaly for this and nothing... always the same with permissions... some one has the magic wand for this problem?

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Finally `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/tone` did the work! I don't know if it's a good practice to do that, simply grant permission all groups for read and execution of entire home directory but well, it's a good workaround for now.